# JPA entity mapping for embedded key

Tags: jpa, mapping, primary-key

I have defined several JPA entities in a Spring Boot application.

```java
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id
    // ...
    //....other fields
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class EntityB {
   @EmbeddedId
   private MyEmbeddedId id;
   // ....other fields
}
```

```java
public class MyEmbeddedId {
   @Column(name = "id_a")
   private String idA;
    
   @Column(name = "color")
   private String color;
}
```

`EntityA` is self-sufifcient, `EntityB` has a composite key, one of whose constituent is primary key of `EntityA`(represented by column `id_a`). So I use embedded key feature here. There is a one-to-many relationship between `EntityA` and `EntityB`. An instance of `EntityA` can be mapped to multiple instances of `EntityB`.

Now, my objective is to fetch `EntityA` with all its associated `EntityB`.

How to go about mapping for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below Entity mappings,

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myEmbeddedId.idA",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<EntityB> entityB;

    // ...
    //....other fields
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
   @EmbeddedId
   private MyEmbeddedId myEmbeddedId;
   // ....other fields
}

public class MyEmbeddedId {
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name="id_a")
   private EntityA idA;

   @Column(name = "color")
   private String color;
}
```

When you load EntityA, it will load all associated EntityB.

Comment: @Mandroid Have you tried the configuration?